# If $f$ is entire and $\exp(f(z))$ is a polynomial, then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, exponential-function

In a recent question that was just deleted, @danielfischer gave at the end of his answer the following exercise: for entire $f$, $$e^{f(z)} \text{ is a polynomial} \iff f \text{ is constant}$$

I was thinking about how to prove this...my first idea was to use that $\text{Re}(f)$ is majored by some $\log$ function as $z\to \infty$. Any ideas?

Comment: @danielfischer ----

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the type of the singularity of $e^{f(z)}$ in $\infty$.

**Different hint:** Does $e^{f(z)}$ have any zeros?

The first hint generalises to show that $e^{h(z)}$ for analytic $h$ never can have a pole in an isolated singularity of $h$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the second way, and I'm going to chew on the first way to make sure my understanding of it is rigorous. (I think Taylor expand $\exp(f(1/z))$ at zero.)

Comment: I wouldn't mess with Taylor expansions. $f$ itself has an isolated singularity in $\infty$. Use the Casorati-Weierstraß theorem and the mapping properties of $\exp$ to conclude that $e^f$ cannot have a pole.

Answer (score 5):

It can be solved using more elementary tools.

If $\mathrm{e}^{f(z)}$ is a non-constant polynomial, then it has a root (due to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), which contradicts the fact that the exponential does not vanish.